# 6 digit numeric column in MySQL

Tags: mysql

Say I want to maintain a 6 digit ID column for a table in my database -is it possible to specify this at the DB level in MySQL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the MEDIUMINT data type, or more exact, MEDIUMINT(6):

> A medium-sized integer. The signed
>   range is -8388608 to 8388607. The
>   unsigned range is 0 to 16777215.

As you are going to use it as an ID column, you most likely want to make it `UNSIGNED NOT NULL auto_increment`.

Comment: And if it should always be six digits long you might want to use "UNSIGNED ZEROFILL NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT"

Answer (score 1):

You can set the initial value of the `AUTO_INCREMENT` column so that it starts off at 100000:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl (
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
    ...
);

ALTER TABLE tbl AUTO_INCREMENT = 100000;
```

This way, the first number to be inserted will be 100000, the next will be 100001, etc.

If that's not what you're after, you'll have to be more specific...